# Select columns using pandas dataframe.query()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The documentation on `dataframe.query()` is *very* terse http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html .    I was also unable to find examples of projections by web search.

So I tried simply providing the column names: that gave a syntax error. Likewise for typing `select` and then the column names.  So .. how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After playing around with this for a while and reading through [the source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.2/pandas/core/frame.py#L2038-L2128) for `DataFrame.query`, I can't figure out a way to do it.

If it's not impossible, apparently it's at least strongly discouraged. When this question came up on github, prolific Pandas dev/maintainer jreback [suggested using `df.eval()` for selecting columns and `df.query()` for filtering on rows](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16226#issuecomment-299451702).

---

UPDATE:

javadba points out that the return value of `eval` is not a dataframe. For example, to flesh out jreback's example a bit more...

```
df.eval('A')
```

returns a Pandas Series, but

```
df.eval(['A', 'B'])
```

does not return at DataFrame, it returns a list (of Pandas Series).

So it seems ultimately the best way to maintain flexibility to filter on rows and columns is to use `iloc`/`loc`, e.g.

```
df.loc[0:4, ['A', 'C']]
```

output

```
          A         C
0 -0.497163 -0.046484
1  1.331614  0.741711
2  1.046903 -2.511548
3  0.314644 -0.526187
4 -0.061883 -0.615978
```

Comment: but `eval` does not return a DataFrame .. `ret : ndarray, scalar, or pandas object` . In any case upvoted for the effort.

Comment: hm good point. just tried `iris2 = iris.eval(['sepal_length', 'species'])` but the `iris2` I got back was a `list`...with each element a `Pandas Series`. Weird.

Comment: Looks like we're back to `iloc/loc`.  maybe play with that a bit and i can award here.

Comment: udpated my answer. don't consider this a particularly satisfying answer, but think it's the answer.

Comment: Sorry i'm going to renege on the "accept" deal: I found `pandsql` that does what is requested: see my answer below. Hold on.. i'm thinking through this a bit more..    Yes It *is* what I want : just not in the expected format. The inputs `meat` and `births` are `DataFrame`s.  So instead of invoking methods *already* defined on the `df` it is using a method to generate a new one using one or `df`s as input.

Comment: haha you're welcome to withdraw the 'accept' but use pandasql at your peril. lots of bugs. every few months I decide to try it again when I want to write sql, and it never goes well.

Comment: i see. ok i'll put back the accept here: since that's useful info. But will keep my answer below for the curious.  Does the `pandasql` handle basic projection, filtering and aggregation ok?  i.e. does it mostly fail on `join`s?

Comment: `pandasql` is *really* doing the job here. If/when I were to run into bugs i'm tempted to actually **fix** them since the tool is so useful.

Comment: (Multi years later):  _pandasql_ is however ***very*** slow

Comment: Hey! I remember this discussion well. What I've ended up doing for this use case, if I have a pandas project I want to occasionally run SQL queries in, is to create temporary in-memory sqlite databases, which are easy to load a DF and export to DF via pandas, and execute the sql queries in sqlite. Would this work for you? I'll also note that in the three years since we had this conversation, there haven't been any commits to pandasql, which seems unmaintained at this point: https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/

Comment: Yea it was essentially unmaintained since 2017.  Sqlite is v limited dialect but for basic things this can work

Comment: do you have a preferred means of using sql queries on pandas dataframes these days?

Comment: I use it when performance is not important and prefer to use postgres backend since it supports analytics/windowing functions.  Same as years back actually. The other way I do more often is using spark sql

Answer (score 5):

`Dataframe.query` is more like the *where clause* in a SQL statement than the *select part*.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=dates, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

To select a column or columns you can use the following:

```
df['A'] or df.loc[:,'A']
```

or

```
df[['A','B']] or df.loc[:,['A','B']]
```

To use the `.query` method you do something like

`df.query('A > B')` which would return all the rows where the value in column A is greater than the value in column b.

```
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-03  1.265936 -0.866740 -0.678886 -0.094709
2000-01-04  1.491390 -0.638902 -0.443982 -0.434351
2000-01-05  2.205930  2.186786  1.004054  0.386186
2000-01-08 -0.140069 -0.861755 -0.255619 -2.798589
```

Which is more readable in my opinion that boolean index selection with

```
df[df['A'] > df['B']]
```

Answer (score 4):

How about

```py
df_new = df.query('col1==1 & col2=="x" ')[['col1', 'col3']]
```

Would filter rows where col1 equals 1 and col2 equals "X" and return only columns 1 and 3.

but you would need to filter for rows otherwise it doesn't work.

for filtering columns only better use `.loc` or `.iloc`

Comment: This is the best answer for me. Simple and very close to any db query syntax.

Answer (score 2):

## pandasql

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandasql/0.1.0

Here is an example from  the following blog http://blog.yhat.com/posts/pandasql-sql-for-pandas-dataframes.html . The inputs are two `DataFrame`s  `meat` and `births` : and this approach gives the `projections`, `filtering`, `aggregation` and `sorting` expected from sql.

@maxpower did mention this package is buggy: so let's see.. At least the code from the blog and shown below works fine.

```
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

q  = """
SELECT
  m.date
  , m.beef
  , b.births
FROM
  meat m
LEFT JOIN
  births b
    ON m.date = b.date
WHERE
    m.date > '1974-12-31';
"""

meat = load_meat()
births = load_births()

df = pysqldf(q)
```

The output is a pandas `DataFrame` as desired.

It is working great for my particular use case (evaluating us crimes)

```
odf = pysqldf("select %s from df where sweapons > 10 order by sweapons desc limit 10" %scols)
p('odf\n', odf)

 odf
:    SMURDER  SRAPE  SROBBERY  SAGASSLT  SOTHASLT  SVANDLSM  SWEAPONS
0        0      0         0         1         1        10        54
1        0      0         0         0         1         0        52
2        0      0         0         0         1         0        46
3        0      0         0         0         1         0        43
4        0      0         0         0         1         0        33
5        1      0         2        16        28         4        32
6        0      0         0         7        17         4        30
7        0      0         0         0         1         0        29
8        0      0         0         7        16         3        29
9        0      0         0         1         0         5        28
```

**Update** I have done a bunch of stuff with `pandasql` now: calculated fields, limits, aliases, cascaded dataframes.. it is just *so* productive.

**Another update (3 yrs later)**  This works but warning it is ***very*** slow (seconds vs milliseconds) –

Comment: Glad this is working so well for your case. I have been frustrated by it a couple times, but maybe that's on me for not contributing to fix it. Here's the last bug I ran into - [select from multiple tables](https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/issues/46) doesn't work. Which is a shame because that's the kind of operation which reads so much nicer in SQL than in base pandas. I also worry that since this issue has been open for ~18 months, and has no person or even labels assigned to it, the library is probably not well maintained.

Comment: @MaxPower  I am now using `postgresql` dialect with `pandasql` now - as opposed to the default and limited `sqlite`. It is working better so far.

Answer (score 1):

#### Just a simpler example solution (using `get`):

**My goal:**

I want the *lat* and *lon* columns out of the result of the query.

**My table details:**

```
df_city.columns
```

> Index(['name', 'city_id', 'lat', 'lon', 'CountryName',
> 'ContinentName'], dtype='object')

```
# All columns
city_continent = df_city.get(df_city['ContinentName']=='Oceania')

# Only lat and lon
city_continent[['lat', 'lon']]
```

> ```
>   lat lon
> 113883    -19.12753   -169.84623
> 113884    -19.11667   -169.90000
> 113885    -19.10000   -169.91667
> 113886    -46.33333   168.85000
> 113887    -46.36667   168.55000
> ...   ... ...
> 347956    -23.14083   113.77630
> 347957    -31.48023   131.84242
> 347958    -28.29967   153.30142
> 347959    -35.60358   138.10548
> 347960    -35.02852   117.83416
> 3712 rows × 2 columns
> ```